# Jquery canvas div offset

Tags: jquery, css, canvas

I have an issue with the positioning of a canvas element inside a div element using jquery.

```js
$("body").append($("<div></div>").attr("id", "divy"));
$("#divy").css({
  "position":'absolute',
  "cursor":'move',
  "border":'1px solid red',
  "left":'200px',
  "top":'300px',
  "outerHeight":'0px',
  "innerHeight":'0px',
  "margin":'0px',
  "padding":'0px',
  "min-height":'0px',
  "height":'20px',
})
.html("<canvas id=civy width=20 height=20 ></canvas>")
  liney=document.getElementById("civy");
    oba=liney.getContext("2d");
    oba.fillStyle='yellow';
    oba.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You will see that the yellow rectangle nestles right up to the top of the red outline of the div element. The problem is that when I set the height of the canvas element to below 14 the yellow rectangle no longer butts up against the top of the div and a gap is evident. Width will stay butted up to the left of the div as expected.

```
.html("<canvas id=civy width=5 height=5 ></canvas>")
```

```js
$("body").append($("<div></div>").attr("id", "divy"));
$("#divy").css({
  "position":'absolute',
  "cursor":'move',
  "border":'1px solid red',
  "left":'200px',
  "top":'300px',
  "outerHeight":'0px',
  "innerHeight":'0px',
  "margin":'0px',
  "padding":'0px',
  "min-height":'0px',
  "height":'20px',
})
.html("<canvas id=civy width=5 height=5 ></canvas>")
  liney=document.getElementById("civy");
    oba=liney.getContext("2d");
    oba.fillStyle='yellow';
    oba.fillRect(0,0,50,50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This happens in both chrome and explorer.
Is this an anomaly with jquery/canvas/css?

Thanks, Greg

Comment: You are setting your div's `height` to 20px and you need to set its `line-height` to `0` https://jsfiddle.net/dutagwd3/

Comment: OK thanks however I still get a 2 - 3 pixel gap when I set the height to 1 or 2 pixels.

Comment: You're right, you need to set the canvas' `display` to `block` https://jsfiddle.net/dutagwd3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Ok that's got it looking a lot better, thanks for your help Kaiido.